# Gradle exclude module for Copy task

Tags: java, gradle, copy, build.gradle

I have a Copy task set as follow:

```
task copyToLib( type: Copy ) {
   into "$buildDir/myapp/lib"
   from configurations.runtime

   // We only want jars files to go in lib folder
   exclude "*.exe"
   exclude "*.bat"
   exclude "*.cmd"
   exclude "*.dll"

   // We exclude some lib
   exclude group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-api", version: "1.6.2"
}
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{group=org.slf4j, name=slf4j-api, version=1.6.2}] on task ':copyToLib' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy
```

I have the feeling that it's only a syntax issue, any hint?

Comment: Copy is used to copy files. So you can exclude files. You're passing a map instead. Here's the documentation for the various exclude methods of the you can use: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:exclude(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Cool thanks. So if I understood well, following should do the trick: exclude {it.file in configurations.runtime.files {it.name.equals("slf4j-api")}} . I'm not getting any error anymore, but resource is still included...

Comment: No. It should rather look like `exclude "slf4j-api.jar"`, or `exclude { it.file.name.contains('slf4j-api') }`. There is no file in the runtime configuration named slf4j-api.

Comment: The filename will likely be "slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar"

Comment: you should only exclude a group if you excluding by group, or use a closure.

Comment: @LazerBanana: what do you mean by exlcuding a group? Do you have an example? I thought that my above syntax was actually based on a Closure ...

Comment: @hublo check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exclude by group: `exclude group: org.slf4j`

Exclude by module: `exclude module: slf4j-api`

Exclude by file name: `exclude { it.file.name.contains('slf4j-api') }`

Exclude a file: `exclude "slf4j-api.jar"`

**You can exclude by group and module but it needs to go into configurations exclude like this.** Then it's gonna restrict the configuration before copying.

```
task copyToLib( type: Copy ) {
    into "$buildDir/myapp/lib"
    from configurations.runtime {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }

    // We only want jars files to go in lib folder
    exclude "*.exe"
    exclude "*.bat"
    exclude "*.cmd"
    exclude "*.dll"

}
```

And remember to make sure that the directory exists `$buildDir/myapp/lib`

And maybe instead of excluding all other files just include jars?

Comment: Thanks LazerBanana, it works like a charm !! And yeah, 100% agree, an include instead of an exculde will be much better. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write a method to help you

```
static String generateExcludeJar(Map<String, String> map) {
    "$map.name-${map.version}.jar" 
   // All jar names are like name-version.jar when downloaded by Gradle.
}
```

`exclude generateExcludeJar(group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-api", version: "1.6.2")`

Comment: Thanks @aristotll. Yep, that would work, but best for me would really be to exclude a jar based on its group or artifatId. However, as mentioned by Jb Nizet, Copy works **only** (so far I understood) with files, so maybe you suggestion is actually the only possibility.

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle 7.4 with Groovy:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy){

    from configurations.externalLib{
        into '<dest-dir-name>'

        exclude('slf*.jar', '<other jars if needed>')
    }
}

FYI:
configurations {
    externalLib.extendsFrom(implementation)
}
```