# Gradle exclude VS include

Tags: java, gradle, build, include

Thanks to answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693516/gradle-exclude-module-for-copy-task), the following works:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/myapp/lib"
    from configurations.runtime {
        exclude module: 'commons-io'
    }
}
```

I would assume that the following should also work (include instead of exclude):

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/myapp/lib"
    from configurations.runtime {
        include module: 'commons-io'
    }
}
```

But I'm getting following error:

> org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method include() for arguments [{module=commons-io}] on configuration ':runtime' of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.

Is that expected or am I missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy allows you to omit a lot of braces and other unneccessary syntax, but this may also lead to undesired behaviour, like in your case.

A common approach to create a child `CopySpec` via the [`from(Object, Closure)`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#from(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method looks just like your code:

```
[...]
    from 'sourcePath' {
        // configuration closure
    }
[...]
```

First you pass an object, which will be evaluated via `Project.files()`, then you pass a closure for configuration. Braces can be omitted. Easy-peasy.

But, in your example, the expression passed as object is a method call to configure a `Configuration` in a [`ConfigurationContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html), just like in the following common piece of Gradle code:

```
configurations.runtime {
    exclude module: 'xyz'
}
```

So, the passed closure is interpret to configure the `Configuration` (globally, btw.) and not to configure the `CopySpec`. One way to handle this problem is to explicitly set the omitted braces:

```
[...]
    from(configurations.runtime, {
        // configuration closure
    })
[...]
```

Please note: Using the above example you will be able to use both the `exclude()` and the `include()` method, but not the way you used them in your code examples! In a `CopySpec`, you can only exclude (or include) files or file patterns, not modules. The methods simply won't allow you to pass a map, you need to pass a [list of strings](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#exclude(java.lang.String...)) or [another closure](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#exclude(groovy.lang.Closure)).